# linux все содержимое текстовых файлов выводиться в непонятными символами

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

полсе перезагрузки линукса( обычная перезагрузка) во всех фалах  блокнот вся информация которая была написана на русском языке выводиться не понятными символами
содержимое Шаблоны.txt :
Ïàðñèíã ýòî ïðîöåññ íàõîæäåíèÿ èíôîðìàöèè

ýòî òåõíëîãèÿ íà ðàñïîçíàâàíèÿ äàííûõ
èñêàòü â ñâîáîäíîì òåêñòå ïî ïðèçíàêàì íóæíóþ íàì èíôîðìàöèþ

ïàòòåðí èëè ðåãóëÿðíîå âûðàæåíèå ýòî øàáëîí ïî êîòîðîìó áóäåò èñêòüñÿ èíôîðìàöèÿ

Comment: полсе тога как поменял кодировку на utf-8 ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Выполните `export LANG=ru_RU.UTF8` и `export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF8` и проверьте

Comment: То, что приведено в примере - это текст, сохраненный в кодировке Windows-1251, но открытый в Windows-1252 / ISO 8859-1

Answer (score 4):

Файл должен быть открыт в той кодировке, в которой был сохранен.

В текстовом редакторе при открытии файла есть выбор кодировки. Там по умолчанию стоит определять автоматически. В последних версиях редактора там же есть пункт добавить-удалить кодировки.

В более старых версиях [https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/смена_кодировки_в_gedit](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_gedit)
Текстовый редактор Cinnamon это клон старого gedit. Настройка аналогична.

Answer (score 0):

1)на сайте https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru втавить исходный текст.
2)поставить отображать как ISO-8859-15
3)нажать ок